# Trivial PL/SQL block generating frustrating PLS-00103 error

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, aqua-data-studio

I may be going a bit insane, but I keep getting a `PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following...` error. I have pared my program down to the following:

```
BEGIN
    NULL;
END;
/
```

Which I am running within AquaData Studio.

This produces:

- [Error] Script lines 1-2 ... ORA-06550: line 2, column 8:
- PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following...; Script line 2, statement line 2, column 8

I write a decent amount of PL/SQL and normally the above trivial block runs just fine. What the heck is wrong with what I'm doing?

Comment: I would guess that this Aqua Studio thing doesn't support using `/` as the block terminator for PL/SQL. You will need to check the manual to find out how you can run a PL/SQL block (that contains `;`)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the solution was as suggested by @a_horse_with_no_name in his comment. In ADS, you need to open File → Options <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> (that's a comma!) and set the following options on the **General** tab:

- *';' Statement separator* (make sure it is ***not*** ticked)
- *'/' at End of Line Terminates Statement* (make sure it ***is*** ticked)

See screenshot below. Do this, and it all works: [image]