# Declaring a constant to be used in the query

Tags: sql, oracle, constants

I need to run a query where I need to use a constant (so that we can change its value and impacting directly the value used in the query).

```
declare 
QTY_TRESHOLD CONSTANT NUMBER(10,0) := 1;
begin
    select * from FD111200_DBF where M_NB = QTY_TRESHOLD
end;
```

If I try to run the above, I get the following error on the first statement:

```
An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
declare 
QTY_TRESHOLD CONSTANT NUMBER(10,0) := 1

ORA-06550: line 2, column 39:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
   <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
   like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset [SQL State=65000, DB Errorcode=6550] 

Execution time: 0.01s

1 statement(s) failed.
```

What am I doing wrong? Looking at [the sample](http://psoug.org/definition/CONSTANT.htm) of Oracle, it seems that this should be the good syntax. 
Can anyone help me to understand?

Comment: A select within a block needs an INTO. And you're missing a ; in the select statement

Comment: @Aleksej tried that, but it's not fixing the issue. The request still fails on the first statement.

Comment: Where are you running this from? It looks like the first semicolon is being seen as a statement separator. That looks like a client issue. [[As shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33617220/266304), but other clients don't handle PL/SQL or need to be configured to handle it).

Answer (score 1):

More a comment than an answer, but too long for a comment;
I just tried your code adding an `INTO` and a `;`:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE FD111200_DBF(M_NB NUMBER);

Table created.

SQL> insert into FD111200_DBF values (1);

1 row created.

SQL> declare
  2      QTY_TRESHOLD CONSTANT NUMBER(10,0) := 1;
  3      var number;
  4  begin
  5      select M_NB
  6      into var
  7      from FD111200_DBF where M_NB = QTY_TRESHOLD;
  8      --
  9      dbms_output.put_line(var);
 10  end;
 11  /
1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```